# Show nested comments on click, in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested

So I'm working on a reddit-like feed. Users can comment on comments. When the page loads, all the comments are hidden. And when they click show, I want them to see all the comments for that post.

Current problem: When they click on show comments, all the comments appear for every post, not just the one they clicked on.

Code that generates the list in posts_helper.rb

```
def new_print_tree(posts)
  content_tag(:ul) do
    posts.map do |post|
        if post.parent.nil?
          content_tag(:li) do
            content_tag(:div, post.post) do
                content_tag(:div) do
link_to(post.user.username, user_path(post.user), class: "username user" + post.user.id.to_s) + follow_button(post.user) + content_tag(:p, post.post, class: "root" ) + comment_box(post) + show_comment_button + view_comments(post)
                    end #content_tag :div do
            end + #content_tag :div, post.post
            new_print_tree(post.children)
        end #content_tag :li
else
          content_tag(:li, class: "nested_comments") do
            content_tag(:div, post.post) do
                content_tag(:div) do
                    link_to(post.user.username, user_path(post.user), class: "username user" + post.user.id.to_s) + follow_button(post.user) + content_tag(:p, post.post, class: "child" ) + comment_box(post) + show_comment_button + view_comments(post)
                    end #content_tag :div do
            end + #content_tag :div, post.post
            new_print_tree(post.children)
        end #content_tag :li            

      end
    end.join.html_safe #post.map
  end #content_tag ul,class
end #def
```

Jquery code in index.html.erb

```
<%= new_print_tree @posts %>

    <script>

    $(document).on("page:change", function(){
        $(".comment_form").hide();
        $(".nested_comments").hide();

        $(".show_comment").click(function(){
            $(this).prev(".comment_form").show();
                $(this).hide();
        })

        $(".view_comment_button").click(function(){
            $(this).hide();
            $(".nested_comments").show();
        })
    })

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$(this).closest('.nested_comments').show() # or hide()
```

instead of

```
$(".nested_comments").show();
```

Comment: Adding ".closest()" just hid the button and stopped showing the comments.